# Спарсить минимум Html Agility Pack

Tags: c#, xpath

Всем привет. Есть кусок html с которого нужно спарсить min цену

```
<span class="market_table_value">
    <span class="market_listing_price market_listing_price_with_fee">
            1229,67 USD.                </span>
    <span class="market_listing_price market_listing_price_with_fee">
            1175,57 USD.                </span>
    <span class="market_listing_price market_listing_price_with_fee">
            1068,70 USD.                </span>
        <br>
</span>
```

Значение парсю так

```
HtmlNodeCollection asd = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='market_listing_price_listings_block']//div[@class='market_listing_right_cell market_listing_their_price']//span[@class='market_table_value']//span[@class='market_listing_price market_listing_price_with_fee']");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исходя из того, что я вижу по вашим входным данным я бы сделал вот так:

```
string data=""; //в этой переменной должен быть ваш HTML
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(data);
//получаем список всех span в которых содержится цена
var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//span[@class=\"market_listing_price market_listing_price_with_fee\"]"); 
if (nodes == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("Данные не корректны");

float minimal = float.MaxValue;
foreach(var key in nodes)
{
   var price_data = key.InnerText.Trim().Split(' '); //отделяем число от USD
   float temp;
   if(float.TryParse(price_data[0], out temp))
   {
      if (temp < minimal)
          minimal = temp;
   }
 }
```

Тут нужно понимать, что этот код заточен только под тот пример HTML, который вы нам показали.